# Can't find way to debug Internal Server Error (500) caused by new class

Tags: botframework

I've read a lot of the postings about 500 errors because of the channel emulator, but this is not the case here.  I took the standard bot template, which works just fine with the emulator, and replaced it with

```
ConnectorClient connector = new ConnectorClient(new 
Uri(activity.ServiceUrl));
// calculate something for us to return
// int length = (activity.Text ?? string.Empty).Length;
string responseText= 
***Bot_Application2.SilviaRestClass.GetRestResult(activity.Text);***
```

So the issue is in executing the GetRestResult method in the SilivaRestClass.

The code itself works, I'm using it in lots of other places, as it basically sets up a simple 1)get an input utterance in text, 2)send to my SILVIA AI server, and 3)get an utterance back routine.  I have a feeling it has something to do with either private vs public methods, and/or [Serializable], based on what I have read so far.  The code (minus the credentials) is below.  Many thanks, in advance, for any suggestions to try.
           `

```
bool exit = false;
            restResponse = "Hello";
            bool sessionNew = true;
            string viewMessage = null;
            string SILVIAUri = "";
            string SILVIACore = "/Core/Create/unique/silName";
            string SILVIASubmit = "/IO/SetInputManaged/unique/hello";
            string SILVIARead = "/IO/GetAll/unique";
            string SILVIARelease = "/Core/Release/{unique}";
            string SILVIASubKey = "";
            string silName = "";
            string returnMessage = null;
            string holdit = null;
            string holdit2 = null;
            int forHold = 0;
            string responseFromServer = null;
            string isfalse = "false";
            string myURI = null;
            string unique = null;
                //CREATE CORE from SILVIA SERVER
                myURI = SILVIAUri + SILVIACore;
                myURI = myURI.Replace("silName", silName);
                myURI = myURI.Replace("unique", unique);
                System.Net.WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(myURI);
                request.Headers["Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key"] = SILVIASubKey;
                if (sessionNew)
                {
                    Random rnd1 = new Random();
                    unique = rnd1.Next().ToString() + "askgracie";
                    sessionNew = false;
                    WebResponse wResponse = request.GetResponse();
                    Stream dataStream = wResponse.GetResponseStream();
                    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
                    responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    // Clean up the streams and the response.  
                    reader.Close();
                    wResponse.Close();
                }
                //SEND UTTERANCE to SILVIA
                holdit = null;
                myURI = null;
                myURI = SILVIAUri + SILVIASubmit;
                holdit = restResponse;
                // holdit = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(holdit);
                myURI = myURI.Replace("hello", holdit);
                myURI = myURI.Replace("unique", unique);
                if (holdit == "exit")
                {
                    exit = true;
                    myURI = SILVIAUri + SILVIARelease;
                }
                System.Net.WebRequest sendRequest = WebRequest.Create(myURI);
                sendRequest.Headers["Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key"] = SILVIASubKey;
                WebResponse sendResponse = sendRequest.GetResponse();
                Stream sendStream = sendResponse.GetResponseStream();
                StreamReader sendReader = new StreamReader(sendStream);
                string send_ResponseFromServer = sendReader.ReadToEnd();
                // Clean up the streams and the response.  
                sendReader.Close();
                sendResponse.Close();
                holdit = send_ResponseFromServer;
                forHold = holdit.IndexOf("success");
                holdit2 = holdit.Substring(forHold + 9, 5);
                if (holdit2 == isfalse)
                {
                    var simpleUtterResponse = "The bot failed to send the 
                    utterance to SILVIA";
                }
                //GETRESPONSES FROM SILVIA
                returnMessage = null;
                holdit = null;
                responseFromServer = null;
                myURI = SILVIAUri + SILVIARead;
                myURI = myURI.Replace("unique", unique);
                System.Net.WebRequest readRequest = WebRequest.Create(myURI);
                readRequest.Headers["Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key"] = SILVIASubKey;
                WebResponse readResponse = readRequest.GetResponse();
                Stream readStream = readResponse.GetResponseStream();
                StreamReader readReader = new StreamReader(readStream);
                string read_ResponseFromServer = readReader.ReadToEnd();
                viewMessage = read_ResponseFromServer;
                string lastRead = "ID ";
                List<string> myArray = new List<string>(viewMessage.Split(new 
                string[] { "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None));
                foreach (string s in myArray)
                {
                    if (lastRead == "type: voice")
                    {
                        returnMessage = returnMessage + " " + s.Substring(8);
                    }
                    if (s.Length < 11)
                    { lastRead = s;
                    }
                    else
                    { lastRead = s.Substring(0, 11);
                    }

                    if (s.Length < 11)
                    { lastRead = s;
                    }
                    else
                    { lastRead = s.Substring(0, 11);
                    }
                }
                // Clean up the streams and the response.
                //readReader.Close();
                //readResponse.Close();
                if (exit)
                {
                    myURI = SILVIAUri + SILVIARelease;
                    myURI = myURI.Replace("unique", unique);
                    System.Net.WebRequest closeRequest = 
                    WebRequest.Create(myURI);
                    closeRequest.Headers["Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key"] = 
                    SILVIASubKey;
                    WebResponse closeResponse = closeRequest.GetResponse();
                }
                return returnMessage;
        } 
    }
}`
```

Comment: I ended up resolving this by cut/paste the class inside the same namespace and physical .cs file.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up resolving this by cut/paste the class inside the same namespace and physical .cs file. – Brian Garr just now   edit